# Connect Spring Docker to local mysql instance

Tags: mysql, spring, docker

Is it possible for my dockers that run Spring boot services to connect to a MySQL database running on the host?

Using the -p tag when running the docker is ineffective as port binding is not allowed if the port is in use

Comment: Can you show us a minimal-reproducible-example of what you're trying to achieve ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can connect to MySQL DB running on the host.

All you need to do is run the docker container(that contain spring boot services) on `host` network using `--net host` in your docker run command.

Example:

```
docker run -itd --net host --name myapp myimage
```

Make a note that if you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host.

Read more about docker host networking [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)